# Custom ResponseModel in Springfox/Swagger for returning of ObjectNode

Tags: java, json, spring, swagger, springfox

I'd like to use Swagger to provide an API-Documentation for my Spring Boot API. I managed to get Springfox 2.3.0 to work and everything works as expected except for the controllers returning an ObjectNode. Swagger tries to convert the returned class (ObjectNode) to a JSON-Representation and the result is this:

```json
{
    "array": true,
    "bigDecimal": true,
    "bigInteger": true,
    "binary": true,
    "boolean": true,
    "containerNode": true,
    "double": true,
    "float": true,
    "floatingPointNumber": true,
    "int": true,
    "integralNumber": true,
    "long": true,
    "missingNode": true,
    "nodeType": "ARRAY",
    "null": true,
    "number": true,
    "object": true,
    "pojo": true,
    "short": true,
    "textual": true,
    "valueNode": true
}
```

Now I know, that Swagger can't guess which values are contained in the JSON I build, but I'd like to manually add the correct ResponseModel in any form.

The Controller looks something like this:

```java
@ApiOperation(value = "NAME", notes = "NOTES")
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<ObjectNode> getComponentByIdentification(
            @ApiParam(name="customerid", required=true, value="")
            @RequestParam (required = true)
            String customerId){
    return new ResponseEntity<ObjectNode>(someService.getCustomer(customerId), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Is there any way I can provide a custom ResponseJSON to Swagger which is shown in the documentation as Model Schema?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52848924/7519419)?

Answer (score 0):

We can give custom request and response model in swagger api documentation using swagger springfox annotations as shown below

```
@PostMapping
@ApiOperation(value = "Create Article", response = ArticleDTO.class)
@ApiImplicitParams({
@ApiImplicitParam(name = "Article DTO", value = "article", required = true, dataType = "com.example.ArticleDTO", paramType = "body")})
    public Article create(@ApiIgnore Article article) {
        return articleRepository.save(article);
    }
```

Here the request and response is ArticleDTO but will be converted to Article by Jackson but documentation will show what is inside ArticleDTO.java

Is this what you are looking for