# Springfox - Is it possible to document a POJO via annotation if it's not used in a controller

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

As the title says, is it possible to include a POJO in a swagger doc if it's not used in a controller method?

I've tried using the @ApiModel annotation on the POJO class, i.e.:

```
@ApiModel("POJO")
public class Pojo {
  ...
}
```

However, unless the POJO is returned by a controller, I haven't been able to have it appear in the generated swagger docs. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I'm using springfox version 2.9.2, by the way.

Comment: I don't think you have generate swagger docs for a model which is not using anywhere in controller. If your are using ApiOperation or ApiParam or ApiResponse annotations. It should be included in rest docs/swaggar.yml then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with Springfox. You just have to modify your `Docket`. Add `additionalModels` method to your `Docket` implementation:

```
@Autowired
private TypeResolver resolver;

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()

            ...

            .additionalModels(resolver.resolve(Pojo.class));
}
```